# error:Cannot set property author of #<xxx> which has only a getter. But if I change the getter function name, this error disappears

Tags: javascript, class

When the class has only one getter and no setter, it will report an error, but if I change the name of the getter, the error will disappear.

1. The code that will report an error:

```
class Book {
  constructor(author) {
    this.author = author;
  }
  // getter
  get author() {
    return this.author;
  }

}
const novel = new Book('anonymous'); 
console.log(novel.author);
//TypeError: Cannot set property author of #<Book> which has only a getter
```

2. Code that will not report an error:

```
class Book {
  constructor(author) {
    this.author = author;
  }
  // getter
  get writer() {        //just change the name
    return this.author;
  }

}
const novel = new Book('anonymous');
console.log(novel.writer);
//anonymous
```

**update：**

3. Why **doesn't** this code report an error saying that there is only a getter and no setter?

```js
class Book {
  constructor(name) {
    this._author = name;
  }
  // getter
  get author() {
    return this._author;
  }
}

let a = new Book("Mike")
console.log(a.author)
```

Comment: Defining a getter but no setter is fine, defining a setter but no getter is fine, defining a getter and then trying to use a setter that is not defined is NOT fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here.

First, in your **first** example you're assuming that a getter will implicitly create a field/property. It will not! Thus correct way to use it is:

```js
class Book {
  constructor(author) {
    this._author = author;
  }
  // getter
  get author() {
    return this._author;
  }
}
```

**Do note** that in above code, I have created a property called `_author` and a getter called `author`. Thus when you call the getter `author` it will return the underlying property `_author`.

Secondly, your **second example** works, since without you realizing there are actually **two** properties involved:

`this.author` and `this.writer`

Do note that JS is a dynamic language, and it will not complain of non-existent property.

Hope this helps, for more details read about getter and setters in JS [here](https://www.programiz.com/javascript/getter-setter) or on other sites!

Comment: The problem is `this.author = author;` in the first class' constructor, if you do `this.writer = 'something'` in the second class' constructor (or anywhere in the class), you'll get the same error

Comment: @Titus yes thats exactly why i explained above, but my intention is to make sure the OP understands WHY it was causing error.

Comment: Maybe you've did that but I don't see it. The problem is that the OP called `this.author = author` inside the `Book` class, even in your example class, if you call `this.author = 'something';` anywhere inside of it, you'll get the same error.

Comment: I also wonder why `this.author = author;` throws in the constructor, but doesn't if you run it later on the instance if you don't have a setter???

Comment: @M0nst3R I didn't get you, can you throw an example here, or in a new question I'll try to answer.

Comment: @Titus I agree, but from the context of question - OP wanted to understand why it was happening. What I understand from your comment is I didn't demonstrate/answer what will happen when you try to assign to a property without setter. Well that's expected behavior to throw error (whole point of setter-less properties). I'll rest the case here.

Comment: `new (class A{ get x(){} })().x = 1;` doesn't throw nor does it create a property called `x` in the instance.

Comment: @M0nst3R it will throw anywhere in `"use strict";` mode. Even if it is not in `"use strict";` mode, it will definitely throw inside a class when you try to do that (assign to a property that doesn't have a setter).

Comment: @M0nst3R  yes Titus is correct, and to add to his comment - the reason is class's body always uses "strict mode" only!

Comment: Ah, good to know! the console needs to be nerfed!

Comment: @Titus Sorry, I don't understand why I can't write `this.author = author;` in the first class' constructor if I give the `getter` a different name than author?

Comment: @MiraLing not sure what you mean. It will not give error if you change the name of `get author()` to say `get author2()`

Comment: @subdeveloper Thanks, now I understand. I added a new example, can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't have both a property and a getter with the same name

In the first example `this.author` is a getter and you are trying to overwrite it with `this.author = author`

In the second example `this.author` is an unexisting property

Comment: "Unexisting"? But it's defined in the constructor.

Comment: Oh, I think you mean "unexisting" at the time where the constructor tries to assign a value to it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why “In the second example this.author is an unexisting property”, I mean, in my opinion the second example has the same constructor as the first example. Thank you for your answer！

Comment: @MiraLing keep in mind that the `constructor` is called after the getter is defined. (even though the code makes it look like it would be executed first).

Comment: @M0nst3R I didn't know it before! Thanks